# Equivalent of "shift" for a hash to create a $class->next() method

Tags: perl

I almost feel like saying "it's me again!".

Anyway, here we go.

I like using `while $object->next()` style constructs. They appeal to me and seem "neat".

Now, when the thing I'm iterating over is an array, it's straightforward ("`shift @ary or return undef`")

```
sub next {
   my ( $self, $args ) = @_;
   my $next = shift @{ $self->{list_of_things} } or return undef;
   my ( $car, $engine_size, $color )
       = split( /\Q$opts->{fieldsep}/, $next );
   $self->car         = $host;
   $self->engine_size = $engine_size;
   $self->color       = $color;
```

}

In this example I use AUTOLOAD to create the getters and setters and then have those instance variables available in my object during the `while` loop.

I'd like to do something similar but with the "list_of_things" being a `%hash`.

Here's a non-OO example that doesn't make it into the first iteration. Any ideas why?

(The total "list_of_things" is not that big - maybe 100 entries - so to do a `keys(%{$hash})` every time doesn't seem too wasteful to me).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $list_of_things = {
    volvo => {
        color => "red",
        engine_size => 2000,
    },
    bmw => {
        color => "black",
        engine_size => 2500,
    },
    mini => {
        color => "british racing green",
        engine_size => 1200,
    }
};

sub next {
    my $args = $_;
    my @list = keys( %{$list_of_things} );
    return undef if scalar @list == "0";
    my $next = $list_of_things->{ $list[0] };
    delete $list_of_things->{ $list[0] };
    return $next;
}

while ( next()) {
    print Dumper $_;
    print scalar keys %{ $list_of_things }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Am I doing something crazy?

## EDIT:

I tried Ikegami's suggestion.  Of course, Ikegami's example works flawlessly. When I try and abstract a little, so that all that is exposed to the object is a next->() method, I get the same "perl-going-to-100%-cpu" problem as in my original example.

Here's a non-OO example:

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

sub make_list_iter {
   my @list = @_;
   return sub { @list ? shift(@list) : () };
}

sub next {
   make_list_iter( keys %$hash );
}

my $hash = { ... };

while ( my ($k) = next->() ) {
   print Dumper $hash->{$k};
}
```

It does not seem to get past the first step of the while() loop.

I am obviously missing something here...

Comment: There's a ton of CPAN modules that will do this for you... [`List::Gen`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Gen), [`Array::Iterator`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Array::Iterator), etc. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @zaid - Good point... And I agree. There are two reasons:
* I am not able to use external modules without them going through an extended process to get blessed by security
* I want to understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to rely on the hash's builtin iterator (used by each, keys and values), there's nothing stopping you from making your own.

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

sub make_list_iter {
   my @list = @_;
   return sub { @list ? shift(@list) : () };
}

my $list_of_things = { ... };

my $i = make_list_iter(keys %$list_of_things);
while (my ($k) = $i->()) {
   local $Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;
   local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
   say "$k: " . Dumper($list_of_things->{$k});
}
```

Comment: A quick note on `my ($k) = $i->()` vs `my $k = $i->()`, the latter won't work if one of your keys is false (e.g. `"0"`, `""`), but the former will.

Answer (score 4):

The [`each`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#each) operator is a builtin that iterates over hashes. It returns `undef` when it runs out of elements to return. So you could so something like

```
package SomeObject;

# creates new object instance
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless { hash_of_things => { @_ } }, $class
}

sub next {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($key,$value) = each %{ $self->{hash_of_things} };
    return $key;  # or return $value
}
```

Calling `keys` on the hash will reset the `each` iterator. It's good to know this so you can reset it on purpose:

```
sub reset {
    my $self = shift;
    keys %{ $self->{hash_of_things} }
}
```

and so you can avoid resetting it on accident.

The section on tie'ing hashes in [`perltie`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perltie#Tying_Hashes) also has an example like this.

Comment: I know all about `each`. I just didn't think that it would work when called within a method... I think it will be fine for what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @wawawawa it's okay as long as no one else calls `each %$obj`, `keys %$obj`, or `values %$obj` on your object. Which they shouldn't be doing anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how [`List::Gen`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen) could be used to create an iterator from a list:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Gen 'makegen';

my @list_of_things = (   # This structure is more suitable IMO
    {
        make        => 'volvo',
        color       => 'red',
        engine_size => 2000,
    },
    {
        make        => 'bmw',
        color       => 'black',
        engine_size => 2500,
    },
    {
        make        => 'mini',
        color       => 'british racing green',
        engine_size => 1200,
    }
);

my $cars = makegen @list_of_things;

print $_->{make}, "\n" while $cars->next;
```

Comment: No need to change the data structure. `my $iter = makegen keys %$list_of_things;` would do the trick.

Comment: `makegen` has a `(\@)` prototype so it takes a real array.  I just released a new version of List::Gen that among many other things, makes it easier to use lists directly.  You could write `my $iter = list keys %$list_of_things;`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't need `$list_of_things` for later, you can always do something like

```
while(keys %$list_of_things)
{
  my $temp=(sort keys %$list_of_things)[0];
  print "key: $temp, value array: " . join(",",@{$list_of_things->{$temp}}) . "\n";
  delete $list_of_things->{$temp};
}
```

And if you do need it, you can always assign it to a temporary hash reference and perform the same `while` loop on it.